# Print in a loop inside try

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, try-catch

I am trying to print an array inside a try and catch block and finally export that to a `.csv` file but the for loop gives an error:

```
for(y=0; y<rows; y++){ //Error here
            writer.append("" + sum[y]); // and here: that "y is not public..."
            writer.append(',');
}
```

Whole try and catch blocks:

```
try
    {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFileName); 
        writer.append("DisplayName");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("Age");
        writer.append('\n');

        writer.append("MKYONG");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("26");
            writer.append('\n');

            for(y=0; y<rows; y++){
                writer.append("" + sum[y]);
            writer.append(',');
            }
            writer.append('\n');

        writer.append("YOUR NAME");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("29");
        writer.append('\n');

            writer.append("");

        //generate whatever data you want

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to give data type of variable `y`

```
    for(int y=0; y<rows; y++){ //Error here
 --------^
                writer.append("" + sum[y]); // and here: that "y is not public....."
                writer.append(',');
    }
```